# Why does this recursive function rapidly increase memory use?

Tags: python, recursion, memory-management

I wrote the following recursive function in Python to index a `list` of `str` values (with possible repetition of the same value more than once in the list). The function takes in a `list` and returns a `dict` where each entry of the dictionary is the item list (an `str`) and a corresponding `int` index.

```
def make_indices(entries):
    def _make_indices(ent, idxs, idx):
        if not ent:
            return idxs
        else:
            _make_indices(ent[1:], idxs, idx) if ent[0] in idxs \
                else _make_indices(ent[1:], dict({ent[0]: idx}, **idxs), idx+1)
    return _make_indices(entries, {}, 0)
```

I thought this would be an elegant solution, but its memory use rapidly increases with the length of the list. Would someone be able to expain what exactly might be happening that causes this excess memory use?

Comment: My Python is weak, so this is mostly a guess - are you making copies of lists/dictionaries with every recursive step? If so, you'd have to wait until the entire algorithm stops to clear out all of them and in the mean time you'd be holding multiple copies of a list or at least parts of it. This will likely have a `O(n!)` space complexity.

Comment: Are you seeing a stack overflow, or extreme memory use? There could be quadratic memory consumption problems here due to all the temporaries that don't get cleared off the stack until the recursion ends (and quadratic runtime problems from building all those temporaries), but you'd probably hit a stack overflow before that becomes a major issue.

Comment: Also you forgot to `return` in the `else` branch, so this function will usually return `None`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica good catch! Thanks. I do agree that there are copies being made somewhere in the code, but I wanted to know what exactly is being copied in each recursive call of the function that's making the memory usage grow so rapidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing a list `ent[1:]`, will result in a newly allocated shallow copy of the sliced section. Also, as Python doesn't optimize tail end recursion, you're left in a situation where every single slice you make will remain allocated until the outer call terminates.

Try instead calling `ent.pop(0)` to remove the first element of the list, and then pass the list as `ent` without slicing. This way, no new allocation is required

Comment: Interesting point about `ent[1:]`. I can see how that itself can contribute to the rapid increase in memory usage. I was aware of the lack of tail-recursion optimisation in Python, but didn't expect just that to cause such a big issue with memory usage. Will try out the `ent.pop(0)` suggestion to compare.

Comment: @user1953384 the tail-recursion point does always have some memory cost associated with it, as it necessitates stack allocation for every call. However, that cost is increased by allocating new space at each depth.  The values of local variables can't be de-allocated until the function scope terminates (unless you explicitly `del` or reassign the name), and without tail-recursion optimization, all the function scopes will remain open simultaneously until finally returning.